# Python sqlite3 - How do I formulate a condition where we check if an attribute in the table is one of the elements in my list

Tags: python, list, sqlite

Assume I have a list called `my_list`

I want to fetch rows from the `test` table only if the value in the `data` column is present in `my_list`

A hypothetical code will be like

```
import sqlite3 as lite

conn = lite.connect ('database.db')
with conn:
    conn.row_factory = lite.Row
    curr = conn.cursor ()
    curr.execute ('''select * from test
                     where data in :list''', {'list': my_list}) //I know this is not the correct syntax
```

So, how can solve the following problem in Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build up your query string first, then execute it passing your list in as a parameter...

```
query = 'select * from test where data in ({})'.format(','.join(['?']*len(my_list)))
curr.execute(query, my_list)
```